# Padding zeros to the left in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am relatively new to PostgreSQL and I know how to pad a number with zeros to the left in SQL Server but I'm struggling to figure this out in PostgreSQL.

I have a number column where the maximum number of digits is 3 and the min is 1: if it's one digit it has two zeros to the left, and if it's 2 digits it has 1, e.g. 001, 058, 123.

In SQL Server I can use the following:

```
RIGHT('000' + cast([Column1] as varchar(3)), 3) as [Column2]
```

This does not exist in PostgreSQL. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using google is *exactly* how I found this page. It was my number-one google result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to\_char(number) function in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155656/to-charnumber-function-in-postgres)

Comment: Speaking of SQL Server, they have the `format()` function, which will let you use `format(Column1,'000') as Column2`.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You can use the `rpad` and `lpad` functions to pad numbers to the right or to the left, respectively. Note that this does not work directly on numbers, so you'll have to use `::char` or `::text` to cast them:

```
SELECT RPAD(numcol::text, 3, '0'), -- Zero-pads to the right up to the length of 3
       LPAD(numcol::text, 3, '0')  -- Zero-pads to the left up to the length of 3
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: @Yarin [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26379893/124486) is the standardized one function call method with format strings. Using RPAD/LPAD you're converting to strings and then processing the strings. Using to_char, you're just specifying a different method for stringifying.

Comment: @EvanCarroll they're both useful - this one lets you specify a number for the string length - the other requires knowing 'fm' stands for fill mode and lets you specify a format picture

Comment: WARNING: Unlike the classic `printf`, these bone-headed functions will silently chop your string down to size if it doesn't fit. So you might need a `case when length(foo) ...` around it.

Answer (score 77):

The `to_char()` function is there to format numbers:

```
select to_char(column_1, 'fm000') as column_2
from some_table;
```

The `fm` prefix ("fill mode") avoids leading spaces in the resulting varchar. The `000` simply defines the number of digits you want to have.

```
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> with sample_numbers (nr) as (
postgres(>     values (1),(11),(100)
postgres(> )
postgres-> select to_char(nr, 'fm000')
postgres-> from sample_numbers;
 to_char
---------
 001
 011
 100
(3 rows)

postgres=>
```

For more details on the format picture, please see the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: If the number is too long, `to_char` converts it to ###.  O.o

Comment: I'm curious if there is a solution to the issue where if # if longer than specified in to_Char, it converts to ###. Is there anyway to specificy minimum # of zeros and then have larger numbers grow from that ? For example, if you specify 3 for lpad , numbers would be formatted like

001
010
100
..
1001

Comment: @mikehennessy you can use 9's instead, so like `SELECT to_char((10 ^ abc), 'FM9999999000') FROM generate_series(0, 9) abc`

Answer (score 21):

As easy as

```
SELECT lpad(42::text, 4, '0')
```

References:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3665

Comment: FWIW, it looks like Postgres added `right()` in 9.1

Comment: LPAD quietly truncates any data longer than the length you give it, so be careful.

Answer (score 6):

I was frustrated with `LPAD` and `TO_CHAR` since they don't work if your string goes above the minimum length. I can't speak for how efficient this is but you can chain `FORMAT` to give you a minimum sized string, and then replace any spaces with zeros using `REPLACE`

```
with sample_numbers (nr) as (
    values (1),(11),(100),(1000)
)
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT('%3s', nr), ' ', '0')
from sample_numbers;
 replace
---------
 001
 011
 100
 1000
(4 rows)
```

Versus with other methods `TO_CHAR`:

```
with sample_numbers (nr) as (
    values (1),(11),(100),(1000)
)
SELECT to_char(nr, 'fm000')
from sample_numbers;
 to_char
---------
 001
 011
 100
 ###
(4 rows)
```

(Notice the last value is `###` and not `1000`)

And `LPAD`:

```
with sample_numbers (nr) as (
    values (1),(11),(100),(1000)
)
SELECT LPAD(nr::varchar(255), 3, '0')
from sample_numbers;
 lpad
------
 001
 011
 100
 100
(4 rows)
```

(Notice the last value is `100` and not `1000`)

There are other methods involving using `CASE` but I like that the `REPLACE` & `FORMAT` combo doesn't need any variable repetition.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
ltrim(to_char(Column1, '000'))
```