# SQL: Query integer column in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000

I am trying to query a column of type (int) into a string of format (000). For example: If the column value was 1 then the output of the query should be 001

Comment: How are you doing it? Which DBMS? Post your attempt please.

Comment: I apply it on SQL 2000 and SQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select right('000' + convert(varchar(3), intcolumn), 3) from yourtable
```

Note that the output is of type `varchar`. If you will need this output as a number somewhere else, I would suggest doing the formatting in your UI code and keeping it as a number in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which database engine you use.

In SQL Server 2012 and higher:

```
SELECT FORMAT(7, 'D3')
```

The result is this string:

```
007
```

For older versions of SQL Server, see the accepted answer by shree.pat18

For MySQL, look here: [Adding a leading zero to some values in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165104/adding-a-leading-zero-to-some)

For PostgreSQL, look here: [Padding zeros to the left in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379446/padding-zeros-to-the-left-in-postgresql)

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for your comment.